# How to get the PID of my script?

Tags: bash, scripts

If I have the script "script1.sh" and I want to make it print its own PID as a first step. How can I do this in bash?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The PID of the currently running script is `$$`

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0024_0024

> (`$$`) Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a `()` subshell, it expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.

Comment: How do you get the PID of the subshell?

Comment: @trysis In `bash` > 4, the subshell's PID (as any shell's PID) is stored in $BASHPID